# How to configure Jenkinsfile to only run a specific stage when running a daily cron job?

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I've set a cron job to run every night, however I only want it to run stage B within the Jenkinsfile not all of them.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
            cron('@midnight')
        }

    }
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            ...
        }
        stage('B'){
            when {
              allOf {
                expression { env.CHANGE_TARGET == "master" }
                branch "PR-*"
              }
            }

            steps {
                sh """
                echo 'running script'
                make run-script
                """
            }
        }
        stage('C') {
          ...
        }
```

Without removing the conditionals in Stage B, I can't seem to figure out how to specify the cron to explicitly only run Stage B of the Jenkinsfile - I need to run that makefile script only when those conditionals are met OR during the daily midnight cron job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the [Parameterized Scheduler Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/) which enables you to define cron triggers that trigger the job with a specific environment variable, you can then use this variable as a condition to determine which step to execute.
in your case you can use that environment variable in the `when` directive of each stage to determine if it should run or not according to the variable.
Something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'MIDNIGHT_BUILD', defaultValue: 'true', description: 'Midnight build')
    }
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron('''
           0 * * * * %MIDNIGHT_BUILD=true
        ''')
    }
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            when {
                expression { !env.MIDNIGHT_BUILD }
            }
            steps {
               ...
            }
        }
        stage('B') {
            when {
                expression { env.MIDNIGHT_BUILD || env.CHANGE_TARGET == "master" }
            }

            steps {
                sh """
                echo 'running script'
                make run-script
                """
            }
        }
        stage('C') {
            when {
                expression { !env.MIDNIGHT_BUILD }
            }
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```